# extract all the headings(titles) from a ppt slides

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, python-pptx, heading

I am looking for code to extract only the titles from every power point slides. Is there any python function available. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the title of slides of pptx file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818692/get-the-title-of-slides-of-pptx-file-using-python)

Answer (score 4):

Not by Computer vision (this would be more complicated)

But using some libraries it is possible:

```
from pptx import Presentation

filename = "test.pptx" #your ppt filename

prs = Presentation(filename)

for slide in prs.slides:
    title = slide.shapes.title.text
    print(title)
```

Source: [How to read PPT titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818692/get-the-title-of-slides-of-pptx-file-using-python)

Don't forget to install the library:

```
pip install python-pptx
```

Comment: it's showing this error:   title = slide.shapes.title.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: File was not found probably, you have to save ppt in the same directory of python file

Comment: file is found. i am printing the prs and the object is available there.

Comment: <pptx.presentation.Presentation object at 0x7fe0409cd168>

Comment: check if you can find the file by: import os, then print(os.listdir()) that is your working directory.

Comment: ptx.exc.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'Inv.pptx'      i am getting this error now

Comment: I think you didn't install package using pip

Comment: i have that installed ..by removing 'text' from title.text i am getting 'none' as output

Comment: for slide in prs.slides:
     for shape in slide.shapes:
    # print(slide.shapes.text)
        title = shape.text.title
        print(title)

Comment: also tried aboe code and getting output like <built-in method title of str object at 0x7f54396874b0>

Comment: Not all slides have a title placeholder. In this case, `slide.shapes.title` returns `None`. You need a guard in there like perhaps `if slide.shapes.title is None: continue`.

Answer (score -1):

in previous versions there was a function like this buitl-in. But it has been abandoned.

But if you right click in the **Outline view** you can choose **collapse all**, which will give you only the highest level. Then you can **copy paste**, the slide number of course will not be there, but if you paste to Word every title will be a paragraph so applying a number should do it